# Django: dynamic pagination and variable paginate_by

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates

After searching solution for my puzzle I decided to ask one more question on this board.
So. The conditions: 
 - class ListView has `paginate_by = 12`
 - in html-template there is dropdown list with several options to change my `paginate_by` with POST request - works fine at first, changesnumber of objects on page and number of pages of course
 - to show links for pagination I prefer to use recipe from `https://www.tummy.com/articles/django-pagination/` - had to make come corrections, but shows links to different pages in proper
The problem:
 - after changing paginat_by of class ListView, with dropdown list, I move to next page, and `paginate_by` returns to first value = 12, and of course return to previous number of objects on page and number of pages of course
 ... by the way - at first dropdown list show selected number `12`, as should, but after changing value it selects the first value, even if i choose the last one and number of pages is changed according to last value

My questions:
 - Is attribute `paginate_by` returning back to first (12) value every every time the template page is rendered? is there any way to keep it for little longer?
 - I suppose I can kepp it using GET request, putting it in every `href`, but it's not an option with current links recipe from tummy.com

If it will help. Little of code:
Very simple and working changing of `paginate_by` attribute with POST request

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    per_pages = request.POST.get('items_per_page')
    if per_pages:
        self.paginate_by = per_pages

    return super(FlatsList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The dropdown list

```
<div class="items-per-page">
    <form action="." method="post" id="items_on_page">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="sel form-group">
                <select id="items_per_page" name="items_per_page" 
                onchange="this.form.submit()">
                {% for item in per_page_options %}
                <option
                {% ifequal item paginate_by %}
                selected="selected"
                {% endifequal %}
                value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And current variant of tempaltetag for other pages links

```
<div class="col-md-12 clear">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="pagination">
            <ul>
            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">
                    </i> Ранее</a></li>
            {% endif %}

            {% if show_first %}
                <li><a href="?page=1">1</a></li>
                <span class="ellipsis">...</span>
            {% endif %}

            {% for linkpage in page_numbers %}
                {% ifequal page_obj.number linkpage %}
                <li class="active"><a>{{ page_obj.number }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ linkpage }}">{{ linkpage }}</a></li>
                {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if show_last %}
                <span class="ellipsis">...</span>
                <li><a href="?page={{ paginator.num_pages }}">{{ 
             paginator.num_pages }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">
                    Далее <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-lg" 
                    aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks anyway.